# C++ any good method to generate specialization for template class?

Tags: c++, templates

for example, for a template class A:

```
template <class T>
class A {
public:
    void function(const T & r);
};
```

I want to make specialization for char*, char[] type, for example:

```
template <>
class A<char*> {
public:
    void function(const char * r);
};

template <>
class A<char[]> {
public:
    void function(const char * r);
};
```

string specialization actually has these type:

```
<char*>
<wchar_t*>
<const char*>
<const wchar_t*>
<volatile char*>
<volatile wchar_t*>
<const volatile char*>
<const volatile wchar_t*>
<char[]>
<wchar_t[]>
<const char[]>
<const wchar_t[]>
<volatile char[]>
<volatile wchar_t[]>
<const volatile char[]>
<const volatile wchar_t[]>
```

if the template class A has many member functions, I have to write many needless code to cover the 16 string types, and it's boring.

Are there any good method to generate these code ?

Comment: Why do you need all these specializations?

Comment: for example, the std::map cannot support raw string key like char*, char[].  I want to write some container support this type.

Comment: I think use std::map<std::string, int> is a better solution for instead of std::map<char*, int>, it can support string compare

Comment: Don't use `char *` for C++ standard containers unless you are absolutely sure you need to. Use `std::string` instead.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? I can't imagine why you would need all these specializations. Can you tell us the problem you are trying to solve, and maybe we can give some guidance.